# How do I import the content of .PDF files into a Solr index?

Tags: indexing, solr

I have a directory of pdf files: *document.01.pdf*, *document.02.pdf*, and so on. I am running Solr 6.6.2. I have run

```
solr create -c documents
```

to create a core called `documents`. I want to upload the pdf files to Solr and have it index the text that they contain, not just their metadata.

I understand that it's Tikka's job to do the extracting. I understand that it's the job of the `solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler` to call Tikka. My `solarconfig.xml` (which is just the default created by `solr create`) contains the following section:

```
<requestHandler name="/update/extract"
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.meta">ignored_</str>
      <str name="fmap.content">_text_</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

If I run

```
post -c documents path-to-pdf-directory
```

I end up with entries in the index that contain metadata about the PDF files and an `id` that's the full path to the file, but not the file content. What I want is these metadata fields plus an additional field called something like `text` or `content` to contain the text in the PDFs.

Following examples like the one [here](http://makble.com/how-to-extract-text-from-pdf-and-post-into-solr), I also tried commands like

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/documents/update/extract?literal.id=doc1&commit=true' -F "myfile=@document.01.pdf"
```

but this does the same thing.

I've been [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802000/how-do-i-index-documents-in-solr) [all](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-solr-cell-using-apache-tika.html) [over](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler) for documentation on how to do this, but everything I find makes it sound like I'm doing everything right.

How do I do this? This seems like such basic functionality that the fact it isn't obvious makes me think I'm misunderstanding something fundamental.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the value of `fmap.content` for the `ExtractingRequestHandler` to `text_en` because `text_en` is listed as a field type in my managed schema and the text in my documents is in English.

```
<requestHandler name="/update/extract"
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.meta">ignored_</str>
      <str name="fmap.content">text_en</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

Now when I run `post` the contents of my document are indexed as a `text_en` field along with all the other metadata.

Answer (score 2):

you are asking Solr to put all text in a field named **_text** (with a trailing underscore too, I can't make it show here) with this:

```
<str name="fmap.content">_text_</str>
```

If you don't see a field like this after indexing, check that you have such a field defined in schema.xml (with the right indexed/stored attributes). You don't necessarily need to have it defined in schema.xml, it can work via dynamicFields too, but for a quick verification just define it.

Comment: The documentation online talks about copying and modifying schema.xml files, but there are no example schema.xml files in my Solr installation. Apparently now Solr uses dynamically-generated "managed schema". How do I add a \_text\_ field to one of those? Looking for a hand-holding example to walk me through my first time.

Comment: ah sure, you can use either a custom schema.xml or a managed schema, google how to move to custom schema from managed one, not hard, don't have it handy now sorry, in a rush